# Colocar Quais Letras Mais Se Repete E Em Ordem

Tags: python

Como eu faço pra fazer uma função que Percorre Um Texto
Texto = "TESTE"
e a função colocar em ordem pra mim
As letras que mais se repete com Dicionario Ex:
DICIONARIO = {T:2 , E:2 , S:1}
Assim como tem na biblioteca a função Collections eu gostaria que alguem resumisse o codigo dela pra mim porq não estou entendendo como ela funciona

Comment: Conhece a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)?

Comment: Mas eu queria aprender o codigo dessa biblioteca

Comment: Então, por favor, edite sua pergunta e seja mais claro no que deseja. Não precisa economizar palavras para descrever o seu problema e o seu objetivo, bem como as dificuldades que está enfrentando. Convido-te, também, a fazer o [tour] e ler o guia de [ask] antes de mais nada.

Comment: Anderson tem como resumir o codigo que a biblioteca utiliza pra resolver esse problema ?

Answer (score 0):

A classe `Counter` basicamente itera sobre a *string* e a cada caractere ele incrementa o valor no dicionário:

```
texto = 'anderson carlos woss'
quantidade = {}

for caractere in texto:
  quantidade[caractere] = quantidade.get(caractere, 0) + 1

print(quantidade)
# {'a': 2, 'n': 2, 'd': 1, 'e': 1, 'r': 2, 's': 4, 'o': 3, ' ': 2, 'c': 1, 'l': 1, 'w': 1}
```

De fato, a classe `Counter` é uma especialização de `dict` que utiliza o método `update`:

```
class Counter(dict):

    def __init__(self, iterable=None, **kwds):
        '''Create a new, empty Counter object.  And if given, count elements
        from an input iterable.  Or, initialize the count from another mapping
        of elements to their counts.

        >>> c = Counter()                           # a new, empty counter
        >>> c = Counter('gallahad')                 # a new counter from an iterable
        >>> c = Counter({'a': 4, 'b': 2})           # a new counter from a mapping
        >>> c = Counter(a=4, b=2)                   # a new counter from keyword args

        '''
        self.update(iterable, **kwds)
```

O método `update` é sobrescrito pela classe como:

```
def update(self, iterable=None, **kwds):
    if iterable is not None:
        if isinstance(iterable, Mapping):
            if self:
                self_get = self.get
                for elem, count in iterable.iteritems():
                    self[elem] = self_get(elem, 0) + count
            else:
                dict.update(self, iterable) # fast path when counter is empty
        else:
            self_get = self.get
            for elem in iterable:
                self[elem] = self_get(elem, 0) + 1
    if kwds:
        self.update(kwds)
```

Que, de forma bastante simplificada, é o que apresentei inicialmente.

Para retornar os itens em ordem de frequência, basta verificar a implementação do método `most_common`:

```
def most_common(self, n=None):
    if n is None:
        return sorted(self.iteritems(), key=_itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
    return _heapq.nlargest(n, self.iteritems(), key=_itemgetter(1))
```

Ou seja, basta usar a função `sorted`.

Todo o código fonte da classe pode ser visto em https://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Lib/collections.py

Comment: Mas Anderson como eu coloco em ordem no dicionario tipo  2, 'n': 2, 'd': 1, 'e': 1, 'r': 2, 's': 4, 'o': 3, ' ': 2, 'c': 1, 'l': 1, 'w': 1} Aqui oque mais apareceu foi o "S" depois "O" depois "N"  etc..

Comment: @LucasOliveira editado.

Comment: Anderson eu já fiz essa pergunta mas ai esta Orientada a Objeto e eu não to entendendo, eu queria alguma resposta Estruturada

Comment: @LucasOliveira a questão de usar `sorted` não é influenciada por ser ou não orientado a objetos ou estruturado. Chegou a estudar a função? O que não entendeu dela?